# How to add a ontouchlistener or clicklistener on LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I added a ontouchlistener on linearlayout which include a TextView and a ImageView.When I touched the TextView part it works,and the ImageView doesn't work.I want all the linearlayout can get the touch event.What should I do? My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/graytitle_bj1_black"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_boutique"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_jingpin_icon"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/bottom_jingpin"/>
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/nav_boutique_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#F00"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_fenlei"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fenlei"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/bottom_fenlei"/>
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/nav_fenlei_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_dingyue"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_zizhudingyue_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/bottom_dingyue"/>
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/nav_dingyue_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_sousuo"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_sousuo"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/bottom_sousuo"/>
        <View 
            android:id="@+id/nav_sousuo_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
dingyueLL.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            setFlagTrue(Navigation.Dingyue.getPosition());
            setBtnLine();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: you say "My XML is follows:" but you didnt post it

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for your ImageView (need more info), but in the meantime, your `onTouch()` method should probably be returning `true`.

Comment: did you vandalized your own post? I rolled it back

Comment: You have made the `ImageView` clickable, which is why it is consuming touch events and preventing them from being returned to the parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I am sorry.This is my first time to use it,it drives me mad.

Comment: I see. I edited it, so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom linear layout with `onintercepttouchevent`.

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // do whatever you want with the event
        // and return true so that children don't receive it
        return true;    
    }
}
```

check this thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

[adding touch listener for liner layout filled with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463094/adding-touch-listener-for-liner-layout-filled-with-buttons)

Comment: You are so right! actually i saw this a few days ago and i didn't remember, but thats an elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 1):

What i would try is to explicitly add a touch listener to the image, and see what happend. in this listener, dont call the supper, and return false, so the  event will propagate to the next listener, hopefully the layout

```
dingyueLL.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            setFlagTrue(Navigation.Dingyue.getPosition());
            setBtnLine();
            return false;
        }

    });

THEIMAGE.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            return false;
        }

    });
```

also, put a breakpoint in the ontouch function of the listener of the image, to see if it is getting there