# dividing screen into 6 areas with detecting multi touches

Tags: android

I'm an absolute beginner with android, I found a code that detects multitouches and another code that splits the screen into 6 areas 
here is the layout for each code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout     
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

layout for detecting multitouches :

```
    <com.example.multitouch.MultitouchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

my question is how to combine these two layouts? and how to know each touch in which area lies ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: reffer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463119/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent of your layout - `RelativeLayout` and add a `View` with **match_parent** to both sides dimensions above all views what you want. Use flag `View.INVISIBLE` to hide this view.
And add to this this view `ScaleDetector`. That's all.

Comment: hey, Thank you for replying but can I contact you on skype for example ?

Comment: @HayaD sure. catch - pandarium.shustikov